# Action not happening when tapping UIButton

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` placed on a `UIImageView` and `UILabel`.
When i press down the button i want an image to show in the `UIImageView` and the text color of the `UILabel` to be changed, and when i pull up my finger i want the image to disappear and the text color of the `UILabel` changed back to black.

```
- (void)highlightActivity:(id)sender {
    activityImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:activityName]];

    activityLabel.textColor = activityColor;
}

- (void)deHighlightActivity:(id)sender {
    activityLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    activityImage.image = nil;
}
```

It works fine when i press the button and then release, but i have a problem when tapping the button, the image isn't showing at all and the text color isn't changing.

Any ideas how to make it happen when tapping too?

Thanks,
Naor.

Comment: What are your actions set to in the connections inpector?

Comment: highlightActivity - Touch Down.
deHighlightActivity - Touch Up Inside & Outside.

Comment: I think it is not working because you are dealing with 2 different actions. They can't be fired at the same time. Only one or the other. To do this you'll probably have to use touchesBegan: and touchesEnded: to handle what you want.

Comment: I don't need them both to fire. I just need one of them.
My goal is to show an image on the button when i press it, and to remove the picture from the button when i pull the finger up. (whether it's inside or outside i don't care).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you attach both

```
    Touch Up inside and outside on deHighlightActivity.
```

Because, when you pressed the button, you will release (touch up) the button eventually, if you put both touch up inside and outside on deHighlightActivity, that action will be called every time. So that your tapping action calls deHighlightActivity as well.

I don't know what exactly you are trying to do here, but looks like you have some conflicts on your design.

Comment: I want the action to be called all the time.
My problem is that it doesn't happen only when i tap the button.